# Zener diode - Design is not the same as experiment

Tags: diodes, zener

My design :
[image]

The experiment result:

V_R1 = 1.2 V

V_Zener = 2.8V

What happened to my circuit?

Comment: So what do you expect and how the simulation is different from what you expect?

Comment: Does the real voltage supply and resistor actually match your simulation values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: NB: 3.3 V is specified for 76 mA. You have only ... 1.012 mA ... Will add "load line".

Comment: Look at current/voltage curves for your zener and look at zener test current spec.

Comment: Leave open -  several good answers which make the overall Q&A useful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: 3.3 V is specified for the current of 76 mA. See Electrical characteristics @Andy   Thanks.
Take also account of "burden" ammeter resistance ... when measuring current.

You have only ... 1.012 mA. It is logical that voltage is not what you expect.

For finding the QP, I have pictured the "Load line". See the 3.3V @ 76mA, and the "dynamic resistance" which is about ... 1/94.165m = ~ 10.6 Ohm. Ok.

[image]

The same picture with v axis amplified.
One can see and compare the Quiet Point now <-> experimental point (with diode curve  dispersion ...).

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, this is the problem. Thankyou for the explaination.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the data sheet  carefully you will find the test conditions Izt and nominal value:tolerance for Vz.

Compare those with your operating conditions and you will see that there is nothing wrong with the device behaviour, rather your expectations were based on an overly simplified model of device behaviour.

Comment: can you give me some explanation? I am really confused

Comment: I have a few questions, why my 270mAh battery drains after a few hours with this circuit? even though the load only needs 0.3mA.

Answer (score 1):

> *V_Zener = 2.8V*

A 1N4728 zener diode **is not** a 2.8 volt zener diode; it's a 3.3 volt zener diode: -

[image]

Image from [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1684833.pdf). Also consider this: -

[image]

4.2 volts is your supply voltage.

Comment: hmm, but the result of my experiment like that. V_Zener = 2.8 and V_R1 = 1.2. Idk why its happen.

Comment: @renaldyks add them together and you get 4.0 volts so, clearly, you are not supplying 4.2 volts or you have measurement problems.